# Informatica : How to calculate number of rows in flat files in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

How to calculate number of rows in flat files in informatica.
As we are doing in Teradata as `SEL COUNT (*) FROM ABC.ACCT`.

Comment: We need the count (*) before the processing of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the count function in an Aggregator transformation. Do not select any group by ports.